# Как не допустить записи html кода в "базу данных"?

Tags: php, база-данных, json

Принцип работы моего кода следующий: если в введенной строке есть такие строчные смайлики(":)", ":(") то нужно их заменить на картинки. Вот как я это делаю:

```
$smile = array(":)", ":(");
$grafic = array("<img src = './image/Smile.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>",
    "<img src = './image/Sad.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>");    
$new_message = str_replace($smile, $grafic, $message);

$file = "../data/messages.json";
$json_content = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);

if (!empty($new_message)) {
    $json_content[] = array("time" => $time, "user" => $user, "message"  => $new_message);
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json_content, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

Но потом, уже измененную строку мне требуется записать в "базу"(`json` файл) получается следующее:

```
[
    {
        "time": "1499985376",
        "user": "Max",
        "message": "Hello <img src = '.\/image\/Smile.png' alt='Smile' align='middle'>"
    }
]
```

Как мне сделать так что бы в файл записывалось, например, слово "Smile" или "Sad" вместо `HTML` кода?

Comment: А зачем вы преобразовываете текстовые смайлы в картинки до записи в базу? Преобразовывайте их при выводе из базы!

Comment: А если в сообщении было слово "Sad", то после сохранения и восстановления оно станет смайликом? [That makes me a .](http://www.southparkstudios.com/full-episodes/s03e06-sexual-harassment-panda)

Comment: Многие мессенджеры имеют настройку: показывать смайлики как есть или заменять на эмодзи. Очевидно, что они передают и хранят текст, а замену производят на этапе отображения. Это же позволяет менять отображение уже сохраненного текста. А если вы сразу при получении заменили `:)` на кусок HTML, то поменять картинку будет сложно. Поэтому я поддерживаю точку зрения @Visman – преобразовывайте только после вывода из базы.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `strip_tags` удаляет html и php теги из строки.

Пример:

```
echo strip_tags("<p>Какой-то текст</p>");
```

Результат вывода:

> Какой-то текст

Ссылка на [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php)